# Repair about group by linq

Tags: .net, windows, linq, windows-phone-8

```
XDocument xmlthandongdatviet = XDocument.Load(@"Assets/XMLthandongdatviet.xml");
List<thandong> thandong = (from query2 in xmlthandongdatviet.Elements("truyen").Elements("thandongdatviet")
    group query2 by query2.Element("taptruyen").Value into g
    select new thandong
    {
        page = g.Element("tieudetrang").Value,//error is not has Element
        seri = g.Key,
        urltitle = g.Element("duongdantieude").Value //error is not has Element
    }
).ToList();
```

sir, windows phone 8.1 SDK have not "g.element". It just have "g.elementAt" or "g.elements"

File images: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?f...type=1&theater

Help me repair it... Thanks

Comment: so, why not using `g.Elements()`? Each group may contain multiple elements, so you can't simply use `g.Element()` to return single element

Comment: .. or `g.Elements("....").FirstOrDefault().Value`

Comment: use FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault as @har07 suggested and if there is no element found i might throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment, each group may contain multiple elements, so it doesn't make sense to have `.Element()` method which return only one element. Your ultimate goal is unclear, maybe using `FirstOrDefault()`is sufficient :

```
.......
page = (string)g.Elements("tieudetrang").FirstOrDefault(),
seri = g.Key,
urltitle = (string)g.Elements("duongdantieude").FirstOrDefault()
.......
```

Casting element to string as in above sample, instead of accessing element's `Value` property can avoid null reference exception in case the element was not found.